# Generating a Unique String  by UDFunction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I generating a string for my Primarykey column  similar identity function. but its behavior is unexpected.
it Removing all 0 by String and storing only a single character. Correct me Where am i wrong..

```
Alter FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_GenerateBatchNumber]  (@BatchNumber as Varchar(10))
Returns Varchar
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    Select Top(1) @BatchNumber=[BatchNo] From TBL_iBATCH Order by [BatchNo] desc
    IF @BatchNumber is Null
        BEGIN
         Set @BatchNumber ='B000001'
        END
    Else
        BEGIN
          Set @BatchNumber='B'+Convert(Varchar(7),(Cast(SUBSTRING(@BatchNumber,2,7) as Integer)+1))
        END  

    RETURN @BatchNumber

END
```

Comment: Don't you want to go 2,6? instead of 2,7? Length is 7 with b 6 without

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way is to have a computed column using your IDENTITY column.
 
This UDF *will* fail under load and give 2 keys the same

```
ALTER  TABLE TBL_iBATCH
   ADD BatchNumber AS CAST('B' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(MyIDCol AS varchar(6)), 6) AS char(7)) PERSISTED;

ALTER  TABLE TBL_iBATCHWITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TBL_iBATCH PRIMARY KEY (BatchNumber);
```

Comment: ITs Giving B1 instead of B000001

Comment: @Madhav: ah yes, should be varchar, not char. Updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Assumes batchnumber is a fixed lenth.  change substring(@BatchNumber,2,7) as integer...
to

```
 @BatchNumber='B'+Convert(Varchar(7),(Cast(SUBSTRING(@BatchNumber,2,6) as Integer)+1))
```

Reason: your substring is trying to grab a null position 7 when one doesn't exist; that value will be null so only B will be listed as output.

Comment: Still the same o/p. Can you Clarify is this Like happening.For Second query when the casting is Happening 000001 is converted to Integer.Means Is it like 000001+1 or 1+1